# Thread.Sleep method

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        len  = (i*30).ToString();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        progressbar.Style.Add("width", len + "px");
        txtlbl.InnerHtml = len+'%';

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
        //htmlDivControl.Style["width"] =Convert.ToString("10");
                 //Item("width") = i.ToString + "px"
    }
```

This is my code behind code in C#. I have created a div tag in html. And try to increase the width periodically by using sleep method for creating progress bar.
I can see the progress bar only at the end of loop completion.
Just want see the progress bar step by step on width increasing.
What is the problem here.Please any one help me.

Comment: As you said, this is your "behind code" which executes on the server. What you are looking for is a javascript code that executes on the client.

Comment: ASP.NET is a serverside technology to render html, so at the end of the page's lifecycle the html will be sent to the client.  Maybe you can use some jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use server side code to do this.  This will have to be done client side, most likely in javascript.

Think of ASP.NET as building a large string that gets sent to the browser.  As the page goes through it's life cycle everything you do just builds one single string that gets sent down to the browser at the very end.  So whatever state the code leaves the page in at completion of the `Prerender` event is the state that it will be delivered to the browser.  That is why you only ever see the "final" state of your progress bar.

Here is a link to a jQuery progress bar that you should be able to use as a starting point.
http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a server side code to perform actions that will be executed in the client side. The server side code will simply output static HTML to the client (i.e. the browser), and stop executing. You can manipulate the HTML before it gets render; but after this point you need to use Javascript (if that's the client side language) to perform this kind of interactive manipulations of the page.

Your code is basically executing *before* the page is served to the client, thus you only see the final result of this manipulation.

On the `OnLoad` event (i.e. after the page is loaded in the client) you can execute a variant of this C# code using Javascript to achieve that effect. However, it will be a lot simpler to use jQuery to this manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the ASP technology does some processing on the server and sends back an HTML response to the client. So you will need to add client-side Javascript code to make changes to the UI.

Here's one approach (using JQuery) that you could try messing around with (Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5arx/g8kF9/). Basically it uses the `setInterval` function to execute some code every x milliseconds.

```
<div class='expando' id='expando'>
</div>

<p id='pOut'>0s</p>

var msg = 20;//global

setInterval(
    function ()//the code that will be executed
    {

        $('#pOut').text(msg++ + 's');
        $('#expando').css('height', msg * 1.5);

     } 
     ,    1000);//interval time in milliseconds
```